Algorithm for Identifying NDF FX Trades as Buy or Sell
Do you know if there is an algorithm for identifying NDF FX trades as buy or sell? I am working on a project with data from the DTCC dashboard.

I had a look at the data and produced this chart:

When you see all these trades it is clearly difficult to know if a buyer or a seller initiated it.
moreover, I had a look at the columns

Event type: ['TRAD', 'CLRG', 'EXER']
Amendment indicator: [False, True]
Cleared: ['N', 'I', 'Y']
Prime brokerage transaction indicator: [True, False]
Large notional off-facility swap election indicator: [True, False]
Post-priced swap indicator: [False, True]
Package indicator: [False, True]
Package transaction price currency: ['USD', 'TWD']
Package transaction price notation: [1.0, 3.0]
Package transaction spread notation: [3.0, 1.0]

and I do not see any that could help.
Of course, you could look at consecutive trades with same price (only 1/4th of them in my example), and say they are on the same side.
For instance for this sequence:

you can assume with not a lot of risk that the trade at 32.10900 is sell initiated, and hence the next one is too.

Sure, I have additional data that I can use for the analysis, such as the spot bid and offer rates for the trades (intraday data), as well as the points curve (daily data). This can help me classify trades by comparing the outright minus the points with the bid and offer of the spot, and then classify them as either bank buy or sell. However, most trades are negotiated within a spread of 10, 20, 30 pips, which complicates the analysis using this method. I'm not sure if there's an algorithm that can help me identify when a trade was negotiated within a very narrow spread.
